# Syncing Dynamics CRM contacts to Exchange mailcontacts distribution lists

Tags: python, api, dynamics-crm, exchange-server, exchangelib

I am looking for a way to automatically check contacts in Dynamics 365 CRM and sync them to mailcontacts in Exchange online distribution lists.

Does anyone have suggestions on where to start with this?

I was thinking of trying to use python scripts with the exchangelib library to connect to the CRM via API, check the CRM contacts, then connect to Exchange online with API to update the mailcontacts in specific distribution lists if needed.

Does this sound plausible?
Are their more efficient ways of accomplishing this?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using MS Flow? I have done similar thing before using MS Flow to transfer emails from CRM to an online email processing service and retrieving emails back to CRM.